# JIRA account login difficulty

Tags: jira

When I try logging into JIRA system, the system told me "you do not have the permission to log in".

I am sure my login credentials are typed in correctly, otherwise the error message should be "sorry, your username and password are incorrect - please try again."

I have reset my password but problem still exists. Is there any permission that I need to ask JIRA administrator to grant?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a typical setup, you need your JIRA administrator to ensure that your account belongs to the `jira-users` group.

If your organization uses Atlassian Crowd for Single Sign-On, ensure that it's not a Crowd issue by logging in to another Crowd-connected application.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks a lot. My account was not in jira-users group before.